# React js. Array elements show more show less with useHooks useState

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am kinda fresh to react and useState hooks (still learing).
I want to create show more/less button with use of Array and React hooks.
I came across this code with exact result i want to achieve - showing some part of an array, and then showing the rest/ returning to previous state.

The thing is, the code is written with use of class components. I never even learned them, useState is more recent.

How to achieve something like this, but with use of state hook (useEffect?) if is it possible ?

https://jsbin.com/wowaluwipu/1/edit?html,js,output

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()   
    this.state = {
      cars: [
      { "name" : "Audi", "country" : "Germany"},
      { "name" : "BMW", "country" : "Germany" },
      { "name" : "Chevrolet", "country" : "USA" },
      { "name" : "Citroen", "country" : "France" },
      { "name" : "Hyundai", "country" : "South Korea" },
      { "name" : "Mercedes-Benz", "country" : "Germany" },
      { "name" : "Renault", "country" : "France" },
      { "name" : "Seat", "country" : "Spain" },
    ],
      itemsToShow: 3,
      expanded: false
    }

    this.showMore = this.showMore.bind(this);
  }
  
  showMore() {
    this.state.itemsToShow === 3 ? (
      this.setState({ itemsToShow: this.state.cars.length, expanded: true })
    ) : (
      this.setState({ itemsToShow: 3, expanded: false })
    )
  }
  
  render() {
    return <div className="container">
      <h3>Click show more to see more data</h3>
      <div className="row">
        <h3>List of Cars</h3>
        <ul>
          {this.state.cars.slice(0, this.state.itemsToShow).map((car, i) => 
           <li key={i}>{car.name} - {car.country}</li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: You shouldn't have any problem finding tutorials on how to convert a class based component to a functional component that uses hooks such as useState. Asking for someone to convert it for you is not the purpose of Stack Oveflow

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: If you say so. Ok then, i will try find out myself how to convert it, if it is possible. Didnt meant to bother.

Comment: Yes it is definitely possible. If you see `setState` in a class component it is essentially the same as useState hook although the syntax is slightly different

Answer (score 3):

Either way, mine works as well as the others. Just in a bit of a different way.

```
 import React, { useState } from 'react'

function Stacks() {
    const [itemsToShow, setItemsToShow] = useState(3);

    const cars = [
      { "name" : "Audi", "country" : "Germany"},
      { "name" : "BMW", "country" : "Germany" },
      { "name" : "Chevrolet", "country" : "USA" },
      { "name" : "Citroen", "country" : "France" },
      { "name" : "Hyundai", "country" : "South Korea" },
      { "name" : "Mercedes-Benz", "country" : "Germany" },
      { "name" : "Renault", "country" : "France" },
      { "name" : "Seat", "country" : "Spain" },
    ];

    const showmore = () => {
        setItemsToShow(cars.length)
    }

    const showless = () => {
        setItemsToShow(3)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {cars.slice(0, itemsToShow).map((car, index) => <li key={index}>{car.name} - {car.country} </li>)}
            {(itemsToShow === 3) ? <button onClick={showmore}>Show More</button>: <button onClick={showless}>Show Less</button>}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Might not be the efficient way, the only difference is I took out the onliner code from show more and made a separate function show less that resets the original state value which is 3.

I have the same problem when I was just starting in React that I normally see Class Components in tutorials.

Comment: that is a great way to do it, i didnt think of show less case , i just hide it i f it is all done

Comment: I guess there's nothing wrong with yours. We just think differently. Haha, so here's my problem. I normally hate dealing with one liners with ternary operators so that's why I have to change my approach. Nevertheless I have to use Ternary operators most of the time in React because of JSX. haha

Answer (score -2):

hello i had the same problem ,but thanks to help of others it is much clearer
(i cloudnt test if it works myself but that should be it)

```
        import { useState } from "react";

  function App() {
    // const [state, setstate] = useState(initialState) // this is how it initially is
    const [data, setData] = useState({
      cars: [
        { name: "Audi", country: "Germany" },
        { name: "BMW", country: "Germany" },
        { name: "Chevrolet", country: "USA" },
        { name: "Citroen", country: "France" },
        { name: "Hyundai", country: "South Korea" },
        { name: "Mercedes-Benz", country: "Germany" },
        { name: "Renault", country: "France" },
        { name: "Seat", country: "Spain" },
      ],
      itemsToShow: 3,
    }); // i named it data youcan name it whatever suits you

    const showMore = () => {
      data.itemsToShow === 3
        ? // ...data is a spread of the state, that means have all the data and change that
          // particular one, in that case  "itemsToShow"
          setData({ ...data, itemsToShow: data.cars.length })
        : setData({ itemsToShow: 3 });
    };

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h3>Click show more to see more data</h3>
        <div className="row">
          <h3>List of Cars</h3>
          <ul>
            {data.cars.slice(0, data.itemsToShow).map((car, i) => (
              <li key={i}>
                {car.name} - {car.country}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
        // if the items you want to show are equal to the legth of your car list
        then hide the button
        {data.itemsToShow < data.cars.length && (
          <button onClick={showMore}>Show more</button>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }

  export default App;
```

generally you get rid of ,"this", "this.state", and instead of "this.setState" you put your hook directly like "setNewThings" or "SetCrazyStuff", or what so..

You'll get the hang of it with more practice, hope that helps